# How to limit retrieve data on firebase realtime Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to ask about how to limit retrieve data in Android Firebase. Here is my code:

```
private void lookingforHelp(){

    DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Locations");
    dbref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                int limitUser = 0;
                ModelUsersLocation mUserLoct = ds.getValue(ModelUsersLocation.class);
                LatLng yourLatLng = new LatLng(latitude_user, longitude_user);
                LatLng polisiLatLng = new LatLng(mUserLoct.getLatitude(), mUserLoct.getLongitude());
                if (mUserLoct.getPengguna().equals("polisi")){
                    if (SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(yourLatLng, polisiLatLng) < 700) {
                        if (limitUser <= 5){
                            if (mUserLoct.getJangkauan().isEmpty()) {
                                DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Locations").child(mUserLoct.getUser().getUid());
                                HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                                hashMap.put("jangkauan", fuser.getUid());
                                dbref.updateChildren(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        writeNewOrder();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I tried to retrieve data that i want is only less than 5 users, using int limitUser = 0; and it's still not working to retrieve data only less than 5 users.

---

**PROBLEM SOLVED**, I try to create markeroptions and make it into invisible, and then add it into arraylist, if (markers.size() <= 5) {do something}
thank u guys for your help btw i really apreciate it :))

Comment: limitUser++ or limitUser = limitUser + 1 place this code inside If(limitUser<=5) body

Comment: You are not increment the variable that's why you are facing such issue.

Comment: still not working, still retrieve all user on firebase database

Comment: After Condition false, mean you have retrieved 5 users then remove listener..

Comment: Also consider using [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java) to replace the client-side distance check. When you use GeoFire, that check can be done on the server, saving you (and your users) much bandwidth usage.

Comment: @Opriday it's doesn't work, thank u for your help, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I use single event listener and then update it every 3 seconds to reduce bandwidth usage, thank you for your suggestion btw:) I'll try to use GeoFire later

Comment: It honestly sounds doubly inefficient; you're both repeatedly requesting data (using a regular listener will only send you deltas, and only when data changes), *and* requesting too much data (using GeoFire allows the range filter to be done server-side). Of course you can do whatever works for you, but your users will probably appreciate fixing both, and it might make you whole logic simple enough to debug that you can add the `limit to 5 users` requirement.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen alright, I agree about your suggestion, and maybe I will change my firebase to geofire to makes my application more efficient, thank you for your suggestion, I really appreciate it, and I need to learn about geofire to change firebase to geofire. btw about my question above, do you know how to fix it? I tried to fix my problem with every option that I search on google, but it still not working, because its complicated and so much information given that makes me confused

Answer (score 0):

```
public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Vendor>> getVendorsByLimit(int limit) {
    ArrayList<Vendor> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("VENDOR_NODE").limitToLast(limit);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (snapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                        //String value = (String) snapshot.getValue(); //Get all child data
                        //OR
                        //String singleValue = (String) snapshot.child("fullName").getValue(); //Get single child data
                        Vendor model = snapshot.getValue(Vendor.class);
                        String key = snapshot.getKey();
                        arrayList.add(model);
                    }
                }
                data.setValue(arrayList);
            } else {
                data.setValue(null);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "" + databaseError.getMessage());
            data.setValue(null);
        }
    });
}

Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("VENDOR_NODE").limitToLast(limit);

You can sort them by using timeStamp like
-----------------------------------------
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
.child("Conversation").child(conversationID)
.limitToLast(100)
.orderByChild("timestamp")
.startAt(dateToStart)    // pass timestamp from when you want to start filtering
.endAt(dateToEnd);      // pass timestamp till when you want to apply filtering
```